# when i use class in python, the code works but linters show error in code with red mark

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am new to oop
so when I want to have variables/stats in child class and methods for them in parent class so I dont have to repeat, even tho the code works there is squiggly line all over the code
am I doing something wrong

```
class User():
    level_xp = {
        1: 250,
        2: 900,
        3: 4500,
        4: 9000,
        5: 45000
    }

    def exp_after_battle(self):
        self.xp += 2400 * self.base_multiplier

        if self.xp > User.level_xp[self.level]:
            self.xp -= User.level_xp[self.level]
            self.level += 1

    def login(self):
        return 'signed in'


class Witch(User):
    def __init__(self, name, subs):
        self.name = name
        self.xp = 0
        self.level = 1
        self.base_multiplier = subs

    pass


testsubject = Witch('testsubject', 1)
testsubject.exp_after_battle()
testsubject.exp_after_battle()
testsubject.exp_after_battle()
testsubject.exp_after_battle()
testsubject.exp_after_battle()
testsubject.exp_after_battle()

print(testsubject.level)
```

in the problems tab the following error are shown

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'xp' for class 'User':11
Unresolved attribute reference 'base_multiplier' for class 'User':11
Unresolved attribute reference 'xp' for class 'User':13
Unresolved attribute reference 'level' for class 'User':13
Unresolved attribute reference 'xp' for class 'User':14
Unresolved attribute reference 'level' for class 'User':14
Unresolved attribute reference 'level' for class 'User':15
```

the code works i dunno why does linters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to have shared methods in the parent class. However, this also means that all variables that you use in such methods should also be defined in the parent class, i.e., in its `__init__` function. Otherwise it could happen that you introduce a new `Orc` class, but forget to initialize its xp. Then, `exp_after_battle` would reference an undefined variable.

In the same way that you realized that `exp_after_battle` belongs to the parent class, you have to ask yourself the same questions for all attributes. Will all users have a name, a level, xp and so on? And which of these have sensible default values that should not be specified by the subclass? I think setting `self.xp=0`,  `self.level=1` and `self.base_multiplier=1` per default for all users seems sensible. Additionally, all users will have a name, but there is not default value to set, so we should make it a parameter of the `__init__` method. We can then call the `super` function in the subclass in order to set the custom name, as well as all default attributes. Afterwards, we can also set the custom base multiplier.

This leads to the following code:

```py
class User:
    level_xp = {
        1: 250,
        2: 900,
        3: 4500,
        4: 9000,
        5: 45000
    }

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.xp = 0
        self.level = 1
        self.base_multiplier = 1

    def exp_after_battle(self):
        self.xp += 2400 * self.base_multiplier

        if self.xp > User.level_xp[self.level]:
            self.xp -= User.level_xp[self.level]
            self.level += 1

    def login(self):
        return 'signed in'


class Witch(User):
    def __init__(self, name, base_multiplier):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.base_multiplier = base_multiplier


testsubject = Witch('testsubject', 1)
testsubject.exp_after_battle()
testsubject.exp_after_battle()
testsubject.exp_after_battle()
testsubject.exp_after_battle()
testsubject.exp_after_battle()
testsubject.exp_after_battle()

print(testsubject.level)
```

Comment: but the problem is here witch will have it's own stats compared to other classes of heros
so is there no way to have 1 place for methods and 
stats of heros in their classes?

Comment: Do you mean custom variables  or custom values (e.g., a different base multiplier)? Because you cannot use custom variables in the base class, but instead you would have to overwrite or introduce the methods in the subclass. Say, e.g., the witch automatically gets 100 extra exp per battle. Then you would have to overwrite `exp_after_battle` in the subclass `Witch`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the User class with a `__init()__` method to allow it to have its own variables.

```py
class User():
    def __init__(self):
        self.level_xp = {
            1: 250,
            2: 900,
            3: 4500,
            4: 9000,
            5: 45000
        }

    # rest of code...
```